# How to read keystore from db

Tags: java, web-services, cxf, x509certificate

I'm integrating cxf webservices,no spring, messages are signed. As a guide I've used this tutorial [CXF Security](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/ws-security.html).
I want to store x509 certifications or the keystore in the db.
I've overridden WSS4JOutInterceptor.loadCryptoFromPropertiesFile method.

```
@Override
    protected Crypto loadCryptoFromPropertiesFile(String propFilename, RequestData reqData) throws WSSecurityException {
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        ks.load(...);
        X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate) ks.getCertificate("client");

        X509Certificate[] certificates = { certificate};

        CertificateStore cs = new CertificateStore(certificates);
        return cs;
    }
```

But a few issues here:
1. There's an error like

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: provided null name     at
>   javax.security.auth.x500.X500Principal.(X500Principal.java:172)

I've checked and subjectDN is not null
2. I'm not sure if this a way to go and should I attach somehow private key to sign the message

Comment: This may be a duplicate as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184502/storing-public-and-private-keys-in-a-database-or-keystore

Comment: I think I've no problem to read the keystore from db. The problem is with WSS4JOutInterceptor as it reads properties only if I'm not wrong

Comment: Assuming WSS4JOutInrerceptor reads or accepts ONLY Properties type, you can adapt your code for Properties using an Adapter pattern. Hope it would help!

Answer (score 0):

1. The error is because CertificationStore doesn't support aliases
2. The better way would be to implement custom provider by extending CryptoBase

Comment: Not a very helpful answer.  1. Why does lack of support for aliases result in this error?  2. Explain further about extending CryptoBase.